# how to get the get first Sunday of the month using date format?

Tags: c#

Hi I need to check a condition for the first Sunday of the month for a date formatted as YYYYMMDD

```
      var calDate = data.value; // example 20210502 is sunday 

      if (first Sunday of the month)
      {
         do this
      }
      else
      {
         do that
      }
```

I need to check the above condition for the first Sunday of the month

Answer (score 1):

Split your problem in two:

1. parse the string to a `DateTime` object

`var date = DateTime.ParseExact(calDate, "yyyyMMdd", null);`

2. Check if the `DateTime` object refers to the first sunday in a month. For this, it must obviously be a Sunday and the day part must be in the range 1 to 7:

`var isFirstSunday = date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday && date.Day <= 7;`

Answer (score 0):

Thsi function can return true or false if the date is first Sunday of the month or not

```
        private static bool IsFirstSunday(DateTime date)
        {
            int i = 1;
            while (i!=7)
            {
                if (date.Day==i &&  date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

And use the result in your if condition

```
//First sunday
var date = DateTime.Parse("2021-05-02 11:27 AM");
var result = IsFirstSunday(date);

//Second sunday
date = DateTime.Parse("2021-05-09 11:27 AM");
result = IsFirstSunday(date);

//Non sunday
date = DateTime.Parse("2021-05-04 11:27 AM");
result = IsFirstSunday(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DateTime GetFirstSundayOfMonth(DateTime givenDate)
{
    DateTime firstDayNextMonth = givenDate.AddDays(-givenDate.Day + 1).AddMonths(1);
    int diff = 7 - (int)firstDayNextMonth.DayOfWeek;
    return firstDayNextMonth.AddDays(diff);
}
```

Comment: Please remember to include an explanation, not just code.